# Mobile responsiveness is only visible on the website, but not phone

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design

**Dear Stockoverflow Community,**

I came across the following problem regarding the responsiveness of my website:

The desktop (mobile) version looks like: [deleted]

While the moble version looks like: [deleted]

I have cleared my cache, the cache on CloudFlare + Hosting.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview
The grid display has a minimum width of 220 pixels. ... A timeline widget is a live region of a page which will receive updates when new Tweets become

You could try this in your table:`<td style="width: 25%;min-width: 220px;">`